# how to put a xml into couchDB?

Tags: xml, couchdb

i want to do this:
   1. PUT a xml string to couchdb server. something like:

```
curl -X PUT  http://localhost:5984/db/_design/app/_update/echo/h1
-d "<doc><name1>value1</name1><name2>value2</name2></doc>"
```

2. at the couchdb server side, i parse the xml string into json object.
3. save the json object as a document.

is this possible? how am i supposed to do?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to covert the XML into JSON before you send it to CouchDB. Of course, you could also not convert it and just store it in a JSON field. Your document might look something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "...",
  "_rev": "...",
  "xml": "<doc><name1>value1</name1><name2>value2</name2></doc>",
  ...some other fields...
}
```

You could also store the XML as an attachment: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments That way you can make a call to `/dbName/documentID/storedData.xml` or whatever, and get the file back with the proper XML Content-type.

It really depends on whether you want to get XML back, or whether you want to only work with the JSON after the conversion.

Comment: i want to get the json. so attachment is not suitable, maybe the best way is use a field of json to transfer xml to server, but it's inconvenient when my xml include so many '"' character. they must be escaped manually.

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape them manually. Just turn your XML into a string, which it already looks like it is, and then run json_encode(). It'll take care of all the escaping and formatting for you. Also, you could always translate the XML into PHP objects (fairly simple operation), and then run it through json_encode() and store that in your document.

Answer (score 6):

I found another way to do this, here is sample:

1. create db

   curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/bookstore
2. create design document

   curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/bookstore/_bulk_docs -d @design.doc

where design.doc's content is:

```
{"docs":
  [
    {
        "_id": "_design/app",
        "updates": {
            "xml2json": "
              function (doc, req) {
                if(req.query.doc == null) {
                  return [null, \"doc is null!\\n\"];
                }
                var xmlDoc = req.query.doc.replace(/^<\?xml\s+version\s*=\s*([\"'])[^\1]+\1[^?]*\?>/, \"\");
                var html = new XML(xmlDoc);
                if(doc==null) {
                  doc = {};
                  doc._id=html.BookList.BookData.@isbn13.toString();
                  if(doc._id==null||doc._id==\"\") {
                    doc._id=html.BookList.BookData.@isbn.toString();
                  }
                }
                if (doc._id == null || doc._id == \"\") {
                  return [null, \"doc id is null!\\n\"];;
                }
                doc.title = html.BookList.BookData.Title.text();
                doc.longtitle = html.BookList.BookData.TitleLong.text();
                doc.authors = html.BookList.BookData.AuthorsText.text();
                doc.publisher = html.BookList.BookData.PublisherText.text();
                return [doc, \"ok!\\n\"];
              }"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

3. test _update

   `doc=$(cat isbndb.sample); doc="$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$doc")"; curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/bookstore/_design/app/_update/xml2json/9781935182320?doc="$doc"`

where isbndb.sample's content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ISBNdb server_time="2010-08-11T04:13:08Z">
<BookList total_results="1" page_size="10" page_number="1" shown_results="1">
<BookData book_id="mastering_perl" isbn="0596527241" isbn13="9780596527242">
<Title>Mastering Perl</Title>
<TitleLong></TitleLong>
<AuthorsText>brian d foylt;/AuthorsText>
<PublisherText publisher_id="oreilly_media">Sebastopol, CA : O'Reilly Media, c2007.</PublisherText>
</BookData>
</BookList>
</ISBNdb>
```